# Is there a software that periodically lets me do mental arithmetic exercises?

Tags: scripts, software-recommendation, education

I am aware of my lazy nature and need to push myself towards doing some basic mental arithmetic from time to time. Therefore, I am looking for a software that periodically asks me to do a short mental arithmetic exercise (plus, minus, multiply, divide).

**Criteria:**

- It should allow me to customise the interval time
- It should integrate in the Ubuntu Desktop, i.e. be hidden in the background and only show up (pop-up) during exercise time

Comment: I doubt such software exists, but could be very easily created with a shell or python script.  I'll cook something up tomorrow, please remind me

Comment: Yeah, bsdgames has arithmetic and such but you'd have to automate the periodic popups yourself.

Comment: Dear @Serg, I'm kindly reminding you about your cooking experiment. :)

Comment: So I've posted an answer-in-progress, which I will be editing as I go along. Please take a look, let me know what you think, what functionality to add or remove.  So far this is a console app, but  it will eventually turn into a small popup window.

Comment: Turns out to be a nice question to work on!

Comment: I thank you both for your great efforts! Currently, however, I think I prefer @JacobVlijm Zenity GUI. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### 1. Straightforward version

The script below will produce assignments at random, **+**, **-**, **×** and **÷**. You can (and should) set a maximum number the script may use, as well as the time interval between the assignments.

#### The assignments

The assignments are presented in a Zenity entry window:

[image]

*if the answer is wrong:*

[image]

*If the answer is correct:*

[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from random import randint
import sys
import subprocess
import time

# maximum number & interval
max_n = int(sys.argv[1]); pause = int(sys.argv[2])

def fix_float(n):
    """
    if the assignment is a division, the script divides the random number by a
    number (integer) it can be divided by. it looks up those numbers, and picks
    one of them (at random). if the number is a prime number the assignment is
    changed into another type
    """
    try:
        divs = [i for i in range(2, n) if n%i == 0]
        pick = randint(1, len(divs))
        div_by = divs[pick-1]
        return [str(n)+" : "+str(div_by), int(n/div_by)]
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        pass

def get_assignment():
    """
    get a random number within the user defined range, make the assignment and
    the textual presentation
    """
    n1 = randint(2, max_n); n2 = randint(2, max_n)
    assignments = [
        [str(n1)+" + "+str(n2), n1+n2],
        [str(n1)+" - "+str(n2), n1-n2],
        [str(n1)+" x "+str(n2), n1*n2],
        fix_float(n1),
        ]
    # pick an assignment (type) at random
    assignment = assignments[randint(0, 3)]
    # if the random number is a prime number and the assignment a division...
    assignment = assignment if assignment != None else assignments[1]
    # run the interface job
    try:
        answer = int(subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c",
            'zenity --entry --title="Think hard:" --text='+'"'+assignment[0]+'"'
            ]).decode("utf-8"))
        if answer == assignment[1]:
            subprocess.Popen(["notify-send", "Coolcool"])
        else:
            subprocess.Popen([
                "notify-send", "Oooops, "+assignment[0]+\
                " = "+str(assignment[1])])
    except (subprocess.CalledProcessError, ValueError):
        pass

while True:
    time.sleep(pause)
    get_assignment()
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `mindpractice.py`
2. Run it with the maximum allowed number and the interval time (in seconds) between the assignments as arguments:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/mindpractice.py <max_number> <interval>
   ```

   e.g.

   ```
   python3 /path/to/mindpractice.py 1000 300
   ```

   to do calculations up to figures of `1000`, with a 5 minute break in between the assignments.
3. If all works fine, you can add it to startup applications the usual way, *or* a launcher to toggle can be made, which I might add later :)

#### Note

- The *dividing* might need some explanation. You'd probably not like to calculate in floats. Therefore, if the assignment is a division, the script looks up the numbers it can be divided by, and picks one (at random). If the (main) number turns out to be a prime number, the assignment is changed into another type.

---

### 2. More options

Once you start calculating, you will find out that *dividing* up to figures of (let's say) 100 is much easier than *multiplying* figures up to 100.

With the script below you can (and should) set the maximum of the numbers *per exercise type* (see instructions below the script).

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from random import randint
import sys
import subprocess
import time

levels = sys.argv[1:]
pause = [int(arg.replace("p:", "")) for arg in levels if "p:" in arg][0]

def fix_float(n):
    """
    if the assignment is a division, the script divides the random number by a
    number (integer) it can be divided by. it looks up those numbers, and picks
    one of them (at random). if the number is a prime number the assignment is
    changed into another type
    """
    try:
        divs = [i for i in range(2, n) if n%i == 0]
        pick = randint(1, len(divs))
        div_by = divs[pick-1]
        return [str(n)+" : "+str(div_by), int(n/div_by)]
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        pass

def get_assignment():
    """
    get a random number within the user defined range, make the assignment and
    the textual presentation
    """
    # pick an assignment (type) at random
    track = randint(0, 3)
    arg = ["a:", "s:", "m:", "d:"][track]
    max_n = [int(item.replace(arg, "")) for item in levels if arg in item][0]

    n1 = randint(2, max_n); n2 = randint(2, max_n)
    assignments = [
        [str(n1)+" + "+str(n2), n1+n2],
        [str(n1)+" - "+str(n2), n1-n2],
        [str(n1)+" x "+str(n2), n1*n2],
        fix_float(n1),
        ]
    assignment = assignments[track]     
    # if the random number is a prime number and the assignment a division...
    assignment = assignment if assignment != None else assignments[1]
    # run the interface job
    try:
        answer = int(subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c",
            'zenity --entry --title="Think hard:" --text='+'"'+assignment[0]+'"'
            ]).decode("utf-8"))
        if answer == assignment[1]:
            subprocess.Popen(["notify-send", "Coolcool"])
        else:
            subprocess.Popen([
                "notify-send", "Oooops, "+assignment[0]+\
                " = "+str(assignment[1])])
    except (subprocess.CalledProcessError, ValueError):
        pass

while True:
    time.sleep(pause)
    get_assignment()
```

#### How to use

- Setup the script exactly like the first one, but run it with the arguments (in any order, the script will link the right arguments to the right item):

  - `p:` pause (break between the assignments, in seconds))
  - `s:` subtract (max number to calculate with)
  - `a:` add (max number)
  - `m:` multiply (max number)
  - `d:` divide (max number)

  For example:

  ```
  python3 '/home/jacob/Desktop/num.py' a:10 d:100 s:10 m:10 p:300
  ```

  to show an exercise every five minutes, numbers up to 10, *except* dividing up to figure 100.

---

### 3. Let's get carried away a bit

#### Being able to see some statistics

The version below shows you the statistics after every 10 exercises:

[image]

*Additionally* (might be usefull when used for children), you can see what went wrong in the last 100 incorrectly answered exercises. In a hidden file, both the assignments and their (incorrect) answers are written:

[image]

This logfile is located:

```
~/.calculog
```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from random import randint
import sys
import subprocess
import time
import os

log = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.calculog"

levels = sys.argv[1:]
pause = [int(arg.replace("p:", "")) for arg in levels if "p:" in arg][0]

def fix_float(n):
    """
    if the assignment is a division, the script divides the random number by a
    number (integer) it can be divided by. it looks up those numbers, and picks
    one of them (at random). if the number is a prime number the assignment is
    changed into another type
    """
    try:
        divs = [i for i in range(2, n) if n%i == 0]
        pick = randint(1, len(divs))
        div_by = divs[pick-1]
        return [str(n)+" : "+str(div_by), int(n/div_by)]
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        pass

def get_assignment():
    """
    get a random number within the user defined range, make the assignment and
    the textual presentation
    """
    # pick an assignment (type) at random
    track = randint(0, 3)
    arg = ["a:", "s:", "m:", "d:"][track]
    max_n = [int(item.replace(arg, "")) for item in levels if arg in item][0]

    n1 = randint(2, max_n); n2 = randint(2, max_n)
    assignments = [
        [str(n1)+" + "+str(n2), n1+n2],
        [str(n1)+" - "+str(n2), n1-n2],
        [str(n1)+" x "+str(n2), n1*n2],
        fix_float(n1),
        ]
    assignment = assignments[track]     
    # if the random number is a prime number and the assignment a division...
    assignment = assignment if assignment != None else assignments[1]
    # run the interface job
    try:
        answer = int(subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c",
            'zenity --entry --title="Think hard:" --text='+'"'+assignment[0]+'"'
            ]).decode("utf-8"))
        if answer == assignment[1]:
            subprocess.Popen(["notify-send", "Coolcool"])
            return "ok"
        else:
            subprocess.Popen([
                "notify-send", "Oooops, "+assignment[0]+\
                " = "+str(assignment[1])])
            open(log, "+a").write(assignment[0]+"\t\t"+str(answer)+"\n")
            try:
                history = open(log).read().splitlines()
                open(log, "wt").write(("\n").join(history[-100:])+"\n")     
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass 
            return "mistake"
    except (subprocess.CalledProcessError, ValueError):
        return None

results = []
while True:
    time.sleep(pause)
    results.append(get_assignment())
    if len(results) >= 10:
        score = results.count("ok")
        subprocess.call([
            "zenity", "--info",
            '--title=Latest scores',
            '--text='+str(score)+' out of 10',
            '--width=160',
            ])
        results = []
```

#### How to use

Usage is pretty much exactly like option 2, but you'll have the logfile available and the scores after every 10 assignments.

---

### 4. Ultimate version

The version below is like option 3 (including log file and reports), but has some additional features:

- adds calculating square root

  [image]
- adds using a *range* of numbers, instead of simply set a maximum
- adds the option to only run *specific* calculation types (e.g. only divide and multiply).
- remembers the arguments it was run with the last time, when run without arguments (only first time, arguments *must* be set). If no arguments were set on first run, the script sends a message:

  [image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from random import randint
import sys
import subprocess
import time
import os

"""
Use this script to practice head count. Some explanation might be needed:
The script can be used for the following types of calculating:

Type          argument example      explanation
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
add           a:30-100              to add in numbers from 30-100
subtract      s:10-100              to subtract in numbers from 10-100
multiply      m:10-20               to multiply in numbers from 10-20
divide        d:200-400             to divide in numbers from 200-400
square root   r:1-1000              to find square root in numbers from 1-1000

N.B.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- The argument p: (pause in seconds; break between the assignments) *must* be
  set, for example: p:300 to launch an assignment every 5 minutes
- A calculation type will only run *if* the argument is set for the
  corresponding type. An example: python3 /path/to/script p:60 s:30-60
  will run a subtract- assignment every minute.

Miscellaneous information:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- On first run, arguments *must* be set. After first run, when no arguments
  are used the last set arguments will run, until the script is run with a new
  set of arguments.
- A log file of the last 100 incorrectly answered questions is kept in
  ~/.calculog
- After 10 assignments, the score of the last 10 pops up.
"""

log = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.calculog"
prefs = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.calcuprefs"
levels = sys.argv[1:]

if levels:
    open(prefs, "wt").write(str(levels))
else:
    try:
        levels = eval(open(prefs).read())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        subprocess.call([
            "zenity", "--info",
            '--title=Missing arguments',
            '--text=On first run, the script needs to be run with arguments\n'
            ])

def fix_float(n):
    """
    if the assignment is a division, the script divides the random number by a
    number (integer) it can be divided by. it looks up those numbers, and picks
    one of them (at random). if the number is a prime number the assignment is
    changed into another type
    """
    try:
        divs = [i for i in range(2, n) if n%i == 0]
        pick = randint(1, len(divs))
        div_by = divs[pick-1]
        return [str(n)+" : "+str(div_by), int(n/div_by)]
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        pass

def fix_sqr(f1, f2):
    """
    If the assignment is calculating a square root, this function finds the sets
    of numbers (integers) that make a couple, within the given range.
    """
    q = f1; r = q**(.5); sets = []
    while q < f2:
        r = q**(.5)
        if r == int(r):
            sets.append([int(r), int(q)])
        q = q+1
    if sets:
        pick = sets[randint(0, len(sets)-1)]
        return ["√"+str(pick[1]), pick[0]]

def get_assignment():
    """
    get a random number within the user defined range, make the assignment and
    the textual presentation
    """ 
    args = ["a:", "s:", "m:", "d:", "r:"]
    indc = []
    for i, item in enumerate(args):
        if item in str(levels):
            indc.append(i)

    index = indc[randint(0, len(indc)-1)]
    name = args[index]

    minmax = [
        [int(n) for n in item.replace(name, "").split("-")] \
        for item in levels if name in item][0]

    assignment = None
    # if the random number is a prime number *and* the assignment a division 
    # or a square root...
    while assignment == None:
        n1 = randint(minmax[0], minmax[1]); n2 = randint(minmax[0], minmax[1])
        assignment = [
            [str(n1)+" + "+str(n2), n1+n2],
            [str(n1)+" - "+str(n2), n1-n2],
            [str(n1)+" x "+str(n2), n1*n2],
            fix_float(n1),
            fix_sqr(minmax[0], minmax[1]),
            ][index]
    # run the interface job
    try:
        answer = int(subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c",
            'zenity --entry --title="Think hard:" --text='+'"'+assignment[0]+'"'
            ]).decode("utf-8"))
        if answer == assignment[1]:
            subprocess.Popen(["notify-send", "Coolcool"])
            return "ok"
        else:
            subprocess.Popen([
                "notify-send", "Oooops, "+assignment[0]+\
                " = "+str(assignment[1])])
            open(log, "+a").write(assignment[0]+"\t\t"+str(answer)+"\n")
            try:
                history = open(log).read().splitlines()
                open(log, "wt").write(("\n").join(history[-100:])+"\n")     
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass 
            return "mistake"
    except (subprocess.CalledProcessError, ValueError):
        return None

if levels:
    pause = [int(arg.replace("p:", "")) for arg in levels if "p:" in arg][0]
    [levels.remove(item) for item in levels if "p:" in item]
    results = []
    while True:
        time.sleep(pause)
        results.append(get_assignment())
        if len(results) >= 10:
            score = results.count("ok")
            subprocess.call([
                "zenity", "--info",
                '--title=Latest scores',
                '--text='+str(score)+' out of 10',
                '--width=160',
                ])
            results = []
```

#### How to use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it (again) as `mindpractice.py`. Run it with the following options (as examples)

  Must be set:

  ```
  p:300                to set the interval between assignments to 5 minutes
  ```

  Optional (make a selection):

  ```
  a:30-100             to add in numbers from 30-100 (optional)
  s:10-100             to subtract in numbers from 10-100
  m:10-20              to multiply in numbers from 10-20
  d:200-400            to divide in numbers from 200-400
  r:1-1000             to find square root in numbers from 1-1000
  ```
- Example command:

  ```
  python3 '/path/to/mindpractice.py' p:300 d:10-100 s:10-30  r:300-600
  ```

  to set:

  ```
  p:300                to set the interval between assignments to 5 minutes
  d:10-100             to divide in numbers from 10-100
  s:10-30              to subtract in numbers from 10-30
  r:300-600            to calculate square roots from 300-600
  ```

  while *adding* and *multiplying* are not used.

Then the next time, if the script is run with:

```
python3 '/path/to/mindpractice.py'
```

It will remember the last used arguments

---

Use the version that serves your needs best...

---

Comment: This version is working great so far. Thank you so much!

Comment: @orschiro added an extended version, to differntiate difficulty.

Comment: the log file is a very nice idea! I'm currently trying to get my head around some of the three-digits multiplications and divisions. They are not so straightforward. :)

Comment: just an idea: Sometimes I am so focused on the work that I ignore the `Think Hard` window to finish the work before (e.g. finish writing a sentence). I then forget about the window. Would it be possible that after 5 minutes, the `Think Hard` window automatically regains focus?

Comment: @orschiro absolutely! I was also still chewing on a completely GUI- version (no need to set *anything* from command line, not even the first run), but I am not sure they will allow us to add more meters to the answer :)

Comment: I am sure they will. Your script is just really amazing! :) Will you move the code over to launchpad ultimately?

Comment: @orschiro I think I will, seems to be the appropriate thing to do; gui usually is x- times the amount of code of the actual functionality.

Answer (score 3):

**Introduction:**

The following application produces random integer expressions to be evaluated by the user. The range of randomly-generated expressions depends on user's settings in the main popup window. Upon clicking <kbd>Lets Begin</kbd> button, the session starts indefinitely, until the user hits Cancel button.

[image]

[image]

**Source Code:**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date: Jan 30,2016
# Purpose: A graphical utility for practicing
#          random arithmetic operations
# Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/725287/295286

#    Copyright: Serg Kolo , 2016
#    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#    (at your option) any later version.
#
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#    GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

import sys
import time
import random
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class mathApp(QtGui.QWidget):
   def __init__(self):
       super(mathApp,self).__init__()
       self.mainMenu()

   def mainMenu(self):
      self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 200)

      self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Let's begin",self)
      self.btn.move(20,150)
      self.btn.clicked.connect(self.askQuestions)

      self.lbl1 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
      self.lbl1.move(20,25)
      self.lbl1.setText("Numbers From")


      self.lbl2 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
      self.lbl2.move(20,55)
      self.lbl2.setText("Numbers To")

      self.lbl2 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
      self.lbl2.move(20,85)
      self.lbl2.setText("Repeat (seconds)")

      self.le1 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
      self.le1.move(150,20)

      self.le2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
      self.le2.move(150,50)

      self.le3 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
      self.le3.move(150,80)

      self.lbl3 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
      self.lbl3.move(20,105)

      self.setWindowTitle('Random Integer Arithmetic')

      self.show()

   def askQuestions(self):
       rangeStart = int(self.le1.text())
       rangeEnd = int(self.le2.text())
       sleepTime = int(self.le3.text())
       done=False
       while not done:
          self.show()
          expression = self.generateOperation(rangeStart,rangeEnd)
          correctAnswer = eval(expression)

          prompt = QtGui.QInputDialog() 
          text,ok = prompt.getText(self,"Don't think too hard",expression) 
          if ok:
             if int(text) == correctAnswer:                
                self.showAnswer("CORRECT,YOU ROCK !")
             else :
                self.showAnswer("Nope");
          else:
              done=True

          if done==True:
              self.close()
          time.sleep(sleepTime)


   def generateOperation(self,start,end):
      a = random.randint(start,end)
      b = random.randint(start,end)
      oplist = ['+','-','/','*']
      op = oplist[random.randint(0,3)]
      expr = str(a) + op + str(b) + ''
      return expr

   def showAnswer(self,result):
       popup = QtGui.QMessageBox()
       popup.setText(result)
       popup.exec_()


def main():
   root = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   app = mathApp()
   sys.exit(root.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Dear @Serg, I also want to thank you personally for your extended GUI version.  One question, I just had the exercise `15/14 = 1`. I am not sure how useful such an exercise is. What do you think?

Comment: @orschiro this is `integer arithmetic` .  That's means result is only whole part, no remainder. If you'd like , I could try to implement `decimal` arithmetic as well. Also, please let me know what kind of other options would you like me to implement and add. Currently , I am trying to practice `agile development` method, and communication with client is key in such method. Please let me know.

Comment: that's great to hear! I would love to provide you with more feedback, e.g. a better integration into the Ubuntu Desktop (run script more in background, i.e. minimise after user input). How can I best provide you with further feedback?